# From how much of a planet's surface will the Space Elevator be visible?

Tags: space-elevators

On Earth, from how much of a planet's surface will the Space Elevator be visible, as in "a prominent object in the sky"?

The simple geometry seems straightforward: If we assume the elevator originates from the north pole (which it wouldn't since it should be built on equator) than it should be visible from all of the according hemisphere, since it's much higher than the planet's atmosphere.

But what will the people on the equator actually see in that case? The elevator is pretty much aligned with the horizon for them.

And what about the atmosphere and lighting? During the day we don't see the stars - will we able to notice the SE? Or only in the night? Will we be able to notice all of the length, or only the part in atmosphere? But the string's upper part is lit by the sun almost all the time - since it's much longer than the planet's diameter and the planet doesn't obstruct much. So is there a reason not to see it in daylight?

Also, if it's got a diameter of ten miles, for example, will it really be visible for so far as from thousand miles?

Relation to world building: I am considering a post-apocalyptic civilization, who doesn't navigate by stars but orients itself around a derelict SE that is visible from all the discovered lands.

Comment: [Related meta discussion.](https://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2730/are-we-being-too-picky-about-what-we-call-worldbuilding)

Comment: Space elevator for supergiants, perhaps?  1 mile is **huge** for a space elevator!

Comment: Just to be pedantic, you'd have the space elevator at the equator not the north pole as it has to have a geostationary orbit...

Comment: Yeah, I would reduce the diameter of your elevator.  In Sci-Fi literature, the SE's on various planets are so thin, most of the planet will only notice a glint off the sun, if even, unless you're very close to it.

Comment: Is [Loren's comment](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28822/from-how-much-of-a-planets-surface-will-the-space-elevator-be-visible/28923#comment75876_28824) correct?

Comment: @HDE 226868 , no, I don't think it is. There is no need to see the base of the cable. If it's visible at all - it's a vertical line on the horizon, so seeing only an upper half works as well.

Comment: @Loren Pechtel , regarding the width of the cable. I seem to recall reading that it's width should increase exponentially with the height, so with the materials available now it will be three centimeters wide at ground-level and miles-wide on geostationary orbit. I must admit, though, that I can't back that up with references, nor am I entirely sure I trust the source myself.

Comment: Another thing I read: that the thin cable is for the initial stages of SE and will ideally be built upon and expanded as the project goes on. So the super-advanced tech SE will indeed look like a tower built out of segments that don't stand on each other but are suspended on the cable (or between multiple cables). In that state - there will be actual elevators inside. Again, maybe the plausibility is low, but the materail for fiction grow. That's the tradeoff I will need to make if I go with the idea, but I didn't want to mention these for the sake of keeping the question as clean as possible.

Answer (score 8):

I'm just going to discuss the geometry of the situation. Here's a quick diagram I drew (note: elevator length not to scale):

[image]

The black circle is the planet, the blue line is the elevator, and the red lines are imaginary lines tangent to points on the planet's surface.

At any point on the planet's surface, we can draw a line tangent to it that will intersect the elevator cable at some point. We can then draw a line from that point to the center of the planet (this line will be perpendicular to the tangent line):

[image]

If we approximate the Earth as being spherical and assume that the space elevator is in Low Earth Orbit (LEO), then applying the Pythagorean theorem shows that the further point on Earth's surface at a given time that can see the space elevator is about 41,700 km away -- or at an angle of about 81.3$^{\circ}$ off from the line from the Earth's core to the elevator. This encapsulates a little less than half of Earth at any given time.

Eyes, like everything else, are affected by fundamental physical limits regarding how well they can resolve an object, which depends on its [angular diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter). The angular diameter of an object $d$ meters wide at a distance of $D$ meters is
$$\delta=2\arctan\left(\frac{d}{2D}\right)$$
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_resolution), the minimum angular resolution the human eye can see details at is about 60 arcseconds, or 1/60 of a degree. Objects with smaller angular sizes would still be visible, just as blobs. Plugging in this limit and the elevator's size, we see that a human would be able to resolve the elevator from no more than 55,300 km away -- further than would be blocked by Earth's curvature. This indicates that curvature should be the dominant factor.

There are then further effects, which other answers have discussed in detail -- everything from weather to atmospheric turbulence to, at some times, the object simply not being bright enough for us to see. So I suspect that the above is an overestimate, except under good conditions.

Comment: This also presumes a completely smooth earth surface, which it's not ... from my understanding it's not a perfect sphere, either, but I believe you are as close as it's going to get a real answer here.

Comment: @Paulster2 Good point. I hadn't considered that. I suppose my method is only an approximation then. :P Darn geology and rotation.

Comment: Part 2 is wrong.  Your 5,500 kilometers is eyeball to cable--but at anything like 5,500 kilometers the base of the cable is well below the horizon.  Your red lines in Part 1 are a reasonable approximation of what you can actually see.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I'm talking about seeing any point on the elevator cable.

Comment: But they can't see through the ground.  The closest point on the cable they have line of sight to will be farther than the closest point on the cable.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I think there's perhaps some miscommunication. I'm saying that at any one of the points on the surface, there are lines of site from an observer to points on the cable of the elevator. These lines of site can have arbitrarily long distances.

Comment: Ok, in a sense it's communication.  5,500km from observer to cable.  That number isn't what he's looking for, though--he's looking at survivors on the ground--what counts is the distance to the base of the cable.  How far around the cable they can wander and yet see it to navigate with.

Comment: Actually I think you are going in the wrong direction with angular diameter. I think reflections of sun or moon light would be farthest visible things. Even a dozen kilometres of air would reduce the contrast of anything else too low. But we can assume that the elevator is highly reflective to minimize issues with thermal expansion from sun light.

Comment: @LorenPechtel See [Nox's response](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28822/from-how-much-of-a-planets-surface-will-the-space-elevator-be-visible?noredirect=1#comment76185_28822).

Comment: @HDE226868 Is this still under construction?

Comment: Regarding the last section, the minimum angular diameter the human eye can *resolve* is about 1/60th of a degree. That doesn't mean, however, that objects of smaller angular diameter are necessarily invisible - most stars have effectively zero angular diameter, appearing indistinguishable from perfect point sources of light, but are clearly still visible.

Comment: @JBH Not anymore; I've made some edits.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I appreciate the point; I've mentioned that.

Answer (score 5):

Regardless of the size of the tower, the important thing to note is the maximum visibility given by the atmosphere. In some places, the very, very best visibility you can expect to get (looking at something unlit, which I assume your tower is as it's derelict) is [150km](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/135223109400236E), but it's generally much, much lower. Fog, clouds, rain, any number of pollutants and even pollen will all contribute to your survivors being unable to see the tower, with the mile wide structure fading into invisibility in the distance like a skyscraper in a fog bank.

Of course, you've had an apocalypse. Whether this will decrease the visibility (extra pollutants/particulates in the air) or increase it (fewer humans pumping soot into the air), will have a big effect. Another important note is air humidity. Water vapour will obscure vision at a distance, so a drier place (lets say the Atacama Desert, where there are several high fidelity telescopes for this very reason) will increase visibility. Your chosen location at the north pole will suffer a lot from snow, as even a light snowfall will rapidly reduce the visibility distance.

If you're lucky, the day is clear and the sun is bouncing off the tower at the right angle then HDE 226868's answer about the limits of the human eye and world geometry applies.

The other consideration is sunshine at nighttime. This is a fairly obvious effect if you look for the ISS at the right time, so sunlight glinting off the structure could theoretically make it much easier to spot. Sadly this only works if you're stood on the right side of the tower (if you're in its 'shadow' you can't use this trick) the clouds are clear enough for you to have 360 degree visibility, and you catch it at the right time. At the north pole the 'right time' pretty much encompasses half of the year, thanks to the day/night cycle there, but nearer the equator this will diminish to a short time around dusk/dawn as the tower is eclipsed by the earth.

TL:DR: Less than 100km most days, up to 5000 on clear days and if you're staring in the right direction at nighttime.

All in all: You're better off looking for the Big Dipper. That isn't going anywhere.

Comment: It might be a reasonable assumption to say that the counterweight or upper station would be solar powered and still have working lights visible from the ground. How would that change your answer?

Comment: It makes it a lot more visible at night, but the essence of the answer remains the same: atmospheric effects will almost always dominate and make the tower unreliable for navigation past the hundreds of km's.

Comment: For a more distant view of the cable you'll be looking out of the atmosphere for most of the path.  While clouds or fog will certainly be an issue at times I don't think that's generally going to be the limiting factor.

Comment: Very good point. I'd forgotten that the atmosphere is comparatively tiny, but in daytime you're going to be looking for a (very) low contrast line high in the sky, and at night it'll be subject to exactly the same (and possibly greater if the lights are off) visibility constraints as the stars, so you may as well use those instead.

Answer (score 3):

A real space elevator cable will be invisible to the human eye. The hyper filaments (nanotubes or whatever else is being used) will have to be as small and light as possible, with just enough strength to hold the weight of the cable below them, the climber(s) and a safety factor to account for vibration, possible severing of strands by micrometers and so on.

The cable itself will be tapered so that it is thickest at geostationary orbit (it is supporting the entire mass of the cable below and the pull of the entire cable+counterweight assembly above) and gradually tapering down to the ends. Liftport, a company which hopes too build the real thing, is experimenting with ribbons of material 5cm wide by 13mm thick. The cable will be invisible to the naked eye even when relatively close (you are looking at something essentially like a strip of standard duct tape rising vertically into the atmosphere.

The astute viewer may be able to see evidence of the cable as climbers ascend or descend, especially if (using Liftport's design) the climbers are externally powered by photovoltaic cells energized by ground based lasers. The panels should reflect some of the light and be visible as rising or falling bright "sparks", and should be visible from up to 5000km away, as HDE suggests. As well, if the cable has intermediate stations attached, they should reflect the sun and be visible much the way satellites are visible in orbit, with the strange twist that anything attached to the cable will be fixed in space, not moving through the sky like a conventional satellite.

Comment: While I agree that the individual filaments may be invisible, they will likely be bundled in a manner to provide the ability to share load between fibers - such as how metal cables are braided.  But even with the equivalent of a "braided" bundle of carbon nanotube fibers feet in diameter, they likely will be too thin to resolved at a distance of 1000 miles.

Comment: Isn't Liftport is trying to make a *Lunar* space elevator? The specifications of the cable would be quite different for an Earth based system.

Comment: Liftport wants to build *both* a space and a lunar elevator. Physics supports a lunar elevator; it can be built using current materials like Kevlar, Spectra 100 or M5, while an Earth based geostationary elevator requires materials that are on the edge of theoretically possible.

Comment: You can still see very small or narrow objects if they are bright enough - you could possibly still see a very thin cable glinting in the sunlight. Most stars, for example, have angular diameter so small they can't even be resolved or quantified beyond a zero-diameter point source, yet they are clearly still visible. The human eye does not need to *resolve* an object to be able to *see* it.

Answer (score 3):

Static discharge off the cable might aid visibility. Experiments with long cables in orbit have produced interesting results.

http://www-spof.gsfc.nasa.gov/Education/wtether.html

It won't be moving through the magnetic field like a low orbit does, but it should still be interacting with winds and clouds.

Lightning can be visible for over a hundred miles.

Comment: That would be a really, really great visual.  And also really good for the storyline.  Can you tell us more about this effect (e.g. - about the experiments that produced results, etc.)

Comment: Updated with a tether experiment link.

Comment: I think you've got a really good idea to 'spark' interest in the OP's story for making the cable visible.

Answer (score 2):

Descriptions of the tangential views are important here (because of the premise of the story), but I have a description that is anecdotal, that should be taken into consideration.

When approaching Dubai from inland, the stretch of Sheikh Zayed Highway (a highway lined on either side with hundreds of skyscrapers) from Jumeirah to Umm Sequim is about 10 miles.  The slight elevation increase and the unobstructed view of this thin stretch of skyscrapers can be seen on a clear day coming in on E-66 once you get about 15 miles closer to it.  This is a clear, dry, sunny atmosphere as well.  It isn't that the buildings are under the horizon, either, it's just that they're far away (or the atmosphere obscures it).

So my guess is **a 10 mile wide "tower" (or space elevator) would not materialize into your vision until you are 15 miles++** away from it, maybe a bit more because of it's "solid" nature in the sky.

If you illuminate your Space Elevator somehow very, very brightly, then the dynamics of the horizon are the only thing important.

[image]